# webBrowser in windows forms: how to load html page from resources?

Tags: windows, forms, resources, browser

I have program which has webBrowser component. I need that this component would navigate to page which is in Resources ("1.htm"). Is there anyway to do it? My general wish is that after debuging I would have only one .exe file of program, and all htm pages would be build in it (like pictures and icons), or isnt that posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DocumentText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext) property for that

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.1htm;
```

or

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() 
                           .GetManifestResourceStream("1.htm"))
{
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) 
   { 
       webBrowser1.DocumentText = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
   } 
}
```